# How to add timeout to Runtime.getRuntime().exec(

Tags: command, timeout

My program stucks while executing a command. Can we add a delay timeout in order to proceed even if there is no response from command line ?

```
try {
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().indexOf("WINDOWS") != -1) 
            {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C " + line);
                int exitCode = p.waitFor();
            }
            else
            {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( line );  

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague; I can't really tell what you're asking. However, from what I understand, a [break()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_break_statement.htm) statement may be of use to you. Perhaps using Thread.sleep() followed by a break()?